SetPnPView not working with aggregation
I want to update the view of SharePoint document library to display total no of items.
I can manually go to each view and update but I have 22 libraries and 5 views in each library. There are total 450 sites with same structure, I am ready with entire iterations to all sites --> libraries --> views.
I facing issue with below line:
Set-PnPView -List '03 - Plant Documentation' -Identity 'Category' -Aggregations "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Type='COUNT'/>" 

This line updates the view and add count in view setting as well as shown in below screenshot:

But when I check view it shows like below without count:

As soon as I  open view setting manually and click on save without making any changes in view it starts showing count.
I am not able to catch problem.
Even SetPnPView is not giving error as shown in below screenshot:

I connected site using Connect-PnPOnline command with both -Interactive and -UseWebLogin switch.
